# Spring @RestController - deserialize Object with Set of Objects as Field (Jackson)

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize following JSON:

```
{
  "name":"Test",
  "owners":[
    {
      "username":"admin"
    }
  ]
}
```

To following Object

```
public class ShoppingList {

  private String name;
  private final Set<ShoppingListUser> owners;

  public String getName() {

    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
  }

  public Set<ShoppingListUser> getOwners() {

    return owners;
  }

  @JsonDeserialize(as = HashSet.class, contentAs = ShoppingListUser.class)
  public void setOwners(Set<ShoppingListUser> owners) {

    getOwners().clear();

    if (owners != null) {
        getOwners().addAll(owners);
    }
  }
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/shoppingLists", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public class ShoppingListController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Resource<ShoppingList>> addShoppingList(@RequestBody ShoppingList shoppingList)
    throws ShoppingListException {
  //DoStuff
}
```

The owners are of type **ShoppingListUser**:

```
public class ShoppingListUser {

  private String username;

  private String password;

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

My Problem is that when I send a Post-Request to this Controller with the given JSON the Response will be:

> {"timestamp":1435965015546,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read JSON: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: de.klem.shopping.list.ShoppingList[\"owners\"]->java.util.LinkedHashSet[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: de.klem.shopping.list.ShoppingList[\"owners\"]->java.util.LinkedHashSet[0])","path":"/api/shoppingLists"}

I don't event understand WHY LinkedHashSet occurs in this exception. Didn't i tell Jackson to use `HashSet.class` for deserialization of the Set?

Does anyone see my mistake? I can't :(

For the complete code feel free to visit my github repo: https://github.com/Yannic92/ShoppingList/blob/master/src/main/java/de/klem/shopping/list/ShoppingList.java

All you need to run the Application is Maven and Java.

1. git clone https://github.com/Yannic92/ShoppingList.git
2. cd ShoppingList
3. mvn clean spring-boot:run
4. POST the given JSON to localhost:8080/api/shoppingLists

user: admin

password: password

Comment: Can you please post a complete example of your POJOs? Your current sample won't compile and is missing two classes.

Comment: Hi, That would be too much code for this purpose. I linked my github repo instead. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: We don't want all your code, we want a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: can't really understand the downvote .. i tryed to fulfill your wishes asap ..

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)'s what you should read and do. Don't assume I downvoted.

Comment: I imported your project and poked around a bit.  After a few tries, the answer I've closed this as a duplicate as worked out.  The first answer is what you're looking for.  I'll go and try to clean it up a little bit so that it reads nicer.

Comment: Thank you. While trying to create a minimal example i noticed that the issue is gone when my POJO(ShoppingList) isn't an entity

Comment: Oh my ... Thanks Makoto. I didn't thought, that the Mapper except URIs when I'm using custom controllers. I'm a Spring beginner .. much to learn i have ;) i won't delete the question. Maybe someone else won't get the mistake..